# Can't access other pages from web app along with CSS using nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Sorry if this is a bad question (or a duplicate) as I am new to Stack and Nginx. I recently setup a VPS in Sydney to serve as my Nginx reverse proxy and added the following config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://MyIpHere:8081/;
        }
}
```

I had already set up a qbittorrent-nox server on the machine i wish to proxy and decided I would try to proxy it, however when i ran the config above, while the first page did load it was only HTML. And when i went to log into the application dashboard the screen would go blank and would not load.

I searched the web for this question but couldn't find anything like it. Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Open browser development console. Look at the error log. Most probably all HTML assets have `src="<MyIpHere>/<asset_name>"` and that makes your browser unable to fetch them.

Comment: I do see error messages very similar to this:

The resource from “http://MyIpHere/css/login.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like your qbittorrent-nox server sends wrong `Content-Type` HTTP header for CSS files. It should be `text/css` (see [`X-Content-Type-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options) HTTP header description). Can you check what is your `Content-Type` header value for that file or if it is present at all? [Here](https://imgur.com/a/GuznTzr) is a screenshot to help you find that information.

Comment: If your problems really comes from wrong `Content-Type` header value, here is a kind of solution: [Override `Content-Type` header with proxied requests](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2014-August/044689.html).